# How to skip AttributeError in for loop python and continue the loop

Tags: python, for-loop, error-handling, try-except

I using a 'for loop' to record the IMEI number from multiple files in an array.

When, but when no IMEI is detected the for loop stops indicating AttributeError:rint.

```
    result = getattr(asarray(obj), method)(*args, **kwds)
    AttributeError: rint
```

I have used this method:

```
for IMEI in file():
    try:
        detect the IMEI from the files()
        Append them to the array()
    exception AttributeError:
        print 'File name'
        pass
```

What I would like to do is to skip the error if the IMEI is not detected in the file and then continue with the loop looking for IMEI in other files.

IMEI refers to 16Digit AlphaNumeric code. I use it as a 'string'.

There are 3200 '.dat' files which I processed for finding such a Alpha Numeric text in each file.
Each dat file has some HEX data in it.

Comment: Maybe you should add a reference to what `IMEI` and `file` is in your question, as it is now, your answer to the question makes little sense and makes the question less useful to others.

Answer (score 3):

```
try:
    execute_something()
except AttributeError:
    caught_error()
```

This is how we catch an error in python.
Just add the above code snippet in your for loop.
Replace the functions i used with your own code.

Please ask more if something is still wrong.

Comment: Thanks. 
I am not sure what I should add instead of caught_error().
Can you please give an example. As I tried the AttribueError: handling in similar way.

Comment: just write 'continue' instead of caught_error().
Your way is wrong, that might fail at runtime.
So its better to use try...except here

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer, which works in my case.

Answer:

```
if IMEI is None:
    continue
```

This helps in skipping the loop if the return value is None and as in my case the AttributeError meant the same.